# Decoding string to UTF-8 if string is already defined as r'string' instead of b'string'

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

Reading path strings from a file, the file contains strings like this which have escaped special unicode characters: `/WAY-ALPHA2019-Espan\314\203ol-Episodio-01.mp4`

I need to convert that string of characters into this:
`/WAY-ALPHA2019-Español-Episodio-01.mp4`

Here is some code demonstrating what I am trying to do:

```
>>> stringa = r'/WAY-ALPHA2019-Espan\314\203ol-Episodio-01.mp4'
>>> stringb = b'/WAY-ALPHA2019-Espan\314\203ol-Episodio-01.mp4'

>>> print(stringa)
/WAY-ALPHA2019-Espan\314\203ol-Episodio-01.mp4
>>> print(stringb)
b'/WAY-ALPHA2019-Espan\xcc\x83ol-Episodio-01.mp4'

>>> print(stringa.decode('utf8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?

>>> print(stringb.decode('utf8'))
/WAY-ALPHA2019-Español-Episodio-01.mp4
```

Comment: `decode` is a method that applies to byte strings, not Unicode strings. For example, a Unicode string 'Español' is converted to a UTF-8 bytes string thus: 'encoded = Español'.encode('utf-8') and the resulting byte string is converted back to a Unicode string by calling `s = encoded.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: The "r'string'" terminology here is confusing if you are *actually* asking how to read lines from a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
re.sub(rb'\\([0-7]{3})', lambda match: bytes([int(match[1], 8)]), stringa.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
```

Explanation:

We use the regular expression `rb'\\([0-7]{3})'` (which matches a literal backslash `\` followed by exactly 3 octal digits) and replace each occurrence by taking the three digit code (`match[1]`), interpreting that as a number written in octal (`int(_, 8)`), and then replacing the original escape sequence with a single byte (`bytes([_])`).

We need to operate over bytes because the escape codes are of raw bytes, not unicode characters. Only after we "unescaped" those sequences, can we decode the UTF-8 to a string.

Comment: what is `x` above in `int(x[match], 8)`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the suggested solution, but I cannot figure it out.
Here is what I am trying:
`new_str = re.sub(rb'\\([0-7]{3})', lambda match: bytes([int(x[match], 8)]), old_str.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I got it!

```new_string = re.sub(rb'\\([0-7]{3})', lambda match: bytes([int(match[1], 8)]), old_string.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')```

Comment: Ah yes I made a copy/paste error, apologies, but you got there on your own!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
code from @Jasmijn had a bug/typo.  Here is the working code:
UPDATED: In my case, old_string could include utf-8 chars, so I had to change `.encode('ascii')` to `.encode('utf-8')`, which still works for me.

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(rb'\\([0-7]{3})', lambda match: bytes([int(match[1], 8)]), old_string.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```